# Mysql problem on getting max min and current

Tags: mysql, sql

i know how to use max, min in mysql, but my problem here is can i get the today's current price?
my sql statement is like this

```
SELECT MAX(price) AS highest, MIN(price) AS lowest 
FROM sales
GROUP BY id
```

here's the problem how can i input the current price insert on the statement?

Comment: Use another query, ordered by date (assuming latest = today)? This can be done with a sub query in the select clause here. It can also be done with a JOIN.

Comment: maybe, but will that cost more time to read by the server?

Comment: It really depends on what indices are available/used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join your query that gets the highest and lowest with the `sales` table, and filter the latter to just the current price.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.price AS current, t2.highest, t2.lowest
FROM sales AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT id, MAX(price) AS highest, MIN(price) AS lowest 
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.date = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to get the most recent price is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS highest,
       MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS lowest,
       FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY DATE DESC) as current
FROM sales;
```

If you specifically want today's date, use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(price) AS highest,
       MIN(price) AS lowest,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DATE = CURDATE() THEN price END) as current
FROM sales
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: i think that is right but it won't work if i use group by

Comment: @PeiYuHong . . . I missed that you want this per `id`.  The `id` is *only* included in the SQL statement and no where else in the question.  I updated the answer and still think these are the simplest approaches.